# Table completely ignoring variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim bytoffcut As Byte
Dim strCriteria
strCriteria = "[WOID] = " & Forms![frmAddStockBooking]![MouldWO]

bytoffcut = Nz(DMax("OffcutNo", "dbo_tblOffcuts", strCriteria), 0) + 1
MsgBox bytoffcut
Me.txtOffcut.Value = bytoffcut

Me.WOID.Value = Forms![frmAddStockBooking]![MouldWO]
Me.txtdate.Value = Now()

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? The variable is behaving as expected where bytoffcut increments by one when i create a new record. But when I check the table the field bound to txtOffcut the field reads 1 instead of the incremented value.

EDIT: This code is being used in the On current property of the form. When I create a new record using a button on the form Dmax is used to find the highest offcut No value in a table and add one to it.

This appear to work in the form as the offcut no txtbox increments. But when i look at the table instead of having records with an increasing offcut no Instead all records read 1

Comment: If more than one person could be adding offcuts at the same time, this could lead to overlaps, even corrected as per @KFleschner's suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, no. I want to increment the value when I create a new record

Comment: I just tried that and im still getting the same problem. This is really puzzling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue of multiple records being updated by creating a primary key for the table I am writing to.

I think that because Access could not uniquely identify the record it would edit all the records that met the criteria or something of the ilk. I am not entirely sure myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending your where clause in the DMax like this, assuming the WOID field in the table is an number type and not text or date.

```
"[WOID] = " & Forms![frmAddStockBooking]![MouldWO]
```

Comment: I think you mean not a text or date, rather than autonumber. That would be fine for autonumber.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to evaluate your `DMax()` expression only once, especially if `dbo_tblOffcuts` is a large linked table without a usable index on `[WOID]`.

If your `DMax()` expression can return a Null, use `Nz()` to transform the Null to zero.  Then add one.

```
Dim bytoffcut As Byte
Dim strCriteria
strCriteria = "[WOID] = " & Forms![frmAddStockBooking]![MouldWO]
'Debug.Print strCriteria '
bytoffcut = Nz(DMax("OffcutNo", "dbo_tblOffcuts", _
    strCriteria), 0) + 1
MsgBox bytoffcut
Me.txtOffcut.value = bytoffcut
```

This may not give you what you want when other users are editing `dbo_tblOffcuts`.

Comment: +1 for Nz, and reducing number of queries that need to be fired off

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not solve my problem of every value in the field having the same value. But I took your advice and used Nz()